# Unexpected ArrayList size

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have the following code,

```
if(scores.size() <= 0) {
    scores.add(0, current);
    score1.setText(scores.get(0));
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "array = " + scores.size());


} else if(scores.size() <= 1){
    scores.add(1, scores.get(0));
    scores.add(0, current);
    score1.setText(scores.get(0));
    score2.setText(scores.get(1));
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "array = " + scores.size());
 } else if(scores.size() <= 2) {
    scores.add(2, scores.get(1));
    scores.add(1, scores.get(0));
    scores.add(0, current);
    score1.setText(scores.get(0));
    score2.setText(scores.get(1));
    score3.setText(scores.get(2));
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "array = " + scores.size());
}
```

`scores` is an `ArrayList` holding `String` values,
`current` is a `String` value taken each time the button is pressed and is taken from the `EditText` box.

On running the code, I would expect that the number of elements in the `ArrayList` to increase by 1. But Logcat shows the `ArrayList` size as 1 after the first button click, then 3 and then 7.

What I expect to happen is the `ArrayList` increases by 1 each time, `ArrayList index 0` moves to `index 1` and the new value is put at `index 0`

I cant put my finger on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Remove this: `scores.add(1, scores.get(0));`, or use `scores.set(0, current)` on the following line.

Comment: `On running the code, I would expect that the number of elements in the ArrayList to increase by 1` - why do you expect that if you have multiple `scores.add()` calls in some of your if blocks.

Comment: Some simple debugging, console logging, or just playing computer with pen and paper would clear this up essentially immediately. Have you taken those steps? If so, what was confusing about the results? You add to the list all over the place. Unrelated, but the size of the list will never be less than zero.

Comment: I knew it was something simple. I am still a relative newbie to Java and forgot about the set() method for ArrayList. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You call multiple times an `add` method. Each call adds new element to an array and increase total size by one. If you call three times `add`, array size increase by three (3 * 1).

From the `List` documentation about `void add(int index, E element)`:

> Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list
> (optional operation).  Shifts the element currently at that position
> (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their
> indices).

If you want to insert a new item at specified index and replace old without shift, use `set` method:

```
scores.set(0, current);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. I forgot about the set(), but I also wasn't aware of add() automatically shifting the current index to the next one. So the set() parts are now redundant as I can just add the new score each time.

Comment: No problem, i'm glad i could help you.

Comment: @JamesSmith "add" adds; you may wish to check out its Javadocs. What else would it do besides add an item to a list?